# Change margin value on table with value from a variable with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I select some tables using this:

```
$('.StatusDateTable').each(function() {
var statusLight = $(this).find(".StatusLight").attr("src");
statusLight = statusLight.substring(33).slice(0,-9);

if (statusLight == "Blue") {
    var columns = Math.abs((start - end)-1);
    var columnWidth = 40;
    var marginRight = Math.abs(columnWidth * columns);
```

Now I want to set margin-right="theValueOfmarginRightHere" on the current table, is this possible?

I tried something like:

```
$(this).attr('margin-right=" + marginRight + "');
```

but obviously it doesn't work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$(this).css('marginRight',marginRight + 'px');`

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).css({marginRight:marginRight})
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/):

```
$(this).css('margin-right', marginRight);
```

You might have to add `px` at the end, not sure about this: `marginRight  + 'px'`.

Comments on your code line:

- `margin-right` is no attribute of an HTML element. It is a CSS property. So you cannot set such properties with the `attr()` method.
- Have a look at [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) which parameters the method expects. It is either:

  - `attr(name)` to get the attribute value.
  - `attr(name, value)` to set the value. You **don't** have to create a string like `name=value`.
- When you do string concatenation, you have to be careful with mixing `'` and `"`. Yours would indeed create the string `margin-right=" + marginRight + "` (as you can see from the syntax highlighter). To concatenate the right way, you have to put single quotes at the right spot:

  ```
  'margin-right="' + marginRight + '"'
  //           --^               --^
  ```

  `